# Athena/Presto Split string for In Query

Tags: sql, arrays, split, presto, amazon-athena

Is it possible to use a comma separated string for an `IN` query?

I would like to execute the following query using the string `a,b,c`

`select * from tablename where colname in ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Example - `select * from tablename where colname in (split_string('a,b,c'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `split(string,delimiter)` for splitting string and boolean function `contains(array, element)` to check if array contains value:

```
 select * from tablename where contains(split('a,b,c',','),colname)
```